# Font Size same as Div Height

Tags: html, css

I have an Absolute Element and what I want is to archive that the font size is same as the div size. So basically it will shrink when the browser shrinks.

I've tried to do 1vw but the text is always gonig beyond the div element.
[enter image description here][1]

I cant upload but I would be pretty simple to explain.
So I have an div, div is = 100px width and height, my text is always going beyond the div block, but I want it to shrink even if its not visibale
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egjhy.png

Comment: You may need some JavaScript, is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible in CSS only.
Here is a way :

```js
function setFontSize($el) {
  if ($el.find('span').text().trim().length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  let overflow = false;
  let fontSize = 0;
  const fontStep = 0.15;
  while(!overflow) {
    fontSize += fontStep;
    $el.find('span').css('font-size', fontSize + 'px');
    overflow = $el.find('span').height() > $el.height();
  }
  $el.find('span').css('font-size', (fontSize - fontStep) + 'px');
}

setFontSize($('div'));
$(window).resize(() => { setFontSize($('div')); });

$('#less').click(() => {
  $('div').height($('div').height() * 0.75);
  $('div').width($('div').width() * 0.90);
  setFontSize($('div'));
});

$('#more').click(() => {
  $('div').height($('div').height() * 1.4);
  $('div').width($('div').width() * 1.15);
  setFontSize($('div'));
});

$('#text').on('change keydown keydown', () => {
  $('div span').text($('#text').val());
  setFontSize($('div'));
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div span {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Control the size of the div</p>
<button id="less">-</button>
<button id="more">+</button>
<hr>
<p>Change text</p>
<input type="text" id="text" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
<hr>

<div>
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all thx for you answere, but u maybe dont understand me right. When I shrink the div the text within shoud shrink too.

Comment: I've update my sample

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the width of your div is defined as to exactly how we test whether the text will fit now, but basically we look at the text at a certain font size and see if it fits in the square. If it doesn't we decrease the font size and see whether the text fits now. And so on.

This snippet breaks out if there is so much text that it won't fit at font size 1px and makes the div scrollable instead. You may want to set that font size limit to something else (bearing in mind that some browsers won't let the user zoom more than a few 100% for example).

```js
function shrink() {
  const thediv = document.querySelector('.thediv');
  let size = 16;//initial font size (in px), you may want to set it bigger
  thediv.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

  while (thediv.offsetHeight > window.innerWidth/10) {// divide by 10 because width set to 10vw
    if (size < 1 ) { thediv.style.overflowY = 'scroll'; break; }
    size = size - 0.1;
    thediv.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  }
}
shrink();
window.onresize = shrink;
```

```css
.thediv {
  width: 10vw;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="thediv">Lorem ipsum and some other text here which will be shrunk to fitLorem ipsum and some other text here which will be shrunk to fitLorem ipsum and some other text here which will be shrunk to fitLorem ipsum and some other text here which will be shrunk to fit</div>
```